# Isolating Dilated image part from Original Image

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, isolation

I have performed Morphological Operation on the original gray eye image (imgSrc) to locate the eyelashes part by following code.

```
seClosing = strel('disk', 5); //perform closing   
closeImg = imclose(imgSrc,seClosing);

midImg = closeImg - imgSrc; //Subtract original image from closed image

binaryImg = midImg > 30; //perform binarization with threshold 30
figure,imshow(binaryImg);title('Binarized Image');

seDilate = strel('disk',1); //perform dilation
dialateImg = imdilate(binaryImg,seDilate);
```

I need to isolate detected part of the dialatedImg from the Original Color image(part inside of the circle) keeping remaining part as well as (part outside the circle). I have also try by converting it to double but it is not getting the results.

Take look at the Dilated Image and The image from which i need to subtract detected part.

Comment: please upload your images to tiny.pic (or similar service) and post links to the images. It is very difficult to understand your question without seeing what you are talking about.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9VIuuPlmJntaFlMVTBsRVFRU00/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9VIuuPlmJntdW5tYUloTVE2cTg/view?usp=sharing